# Create independent objects of a class

Tags: java

I want to create more than one object of a class that are independent one from the other.

I call class constructor multiple time in a for loop, but how can I identify this objects?

I tried using a static variable that takes the value of the for loop index, but this variable assume the value of last index of the for loop.

Here is the code:

Maingui.java

```
public class Maingui extends JFrame {

    public static JFrame frame;
    public static JButton runButton;

    public Maingui() throws IOException {

        frame = new JFrame("maingui");
        setSize(1024,700);
        setTitle("maingui");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        runButton = new JButton("Run");
        runButton.addActionListener(new RunBtnListener());
        add(runButton);

    }
}
```

RunBtnListener.java

```
public class RunBtnListener implements ActionListener {

    ArrayList<SecondGui> menus = new ArrayList<SecondGui>();

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

            menus.add(new SecondGui(i));

        }

    }

}
```

SecondGui.java

```
public class SecondGui extends JFrame {

    public static int c;
    JFrame frame;
    JButton button;

    public SecondGui(int i) {

        this.c = i;

        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        setSize(1024,700);
        setTitle("Menu");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        this.setLocation(50*i, 50*i);

        // Set layout manager
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        button = new JButton("B");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("C: " + c);

            }

        });

        add(button);

    }

}
```

When I click on the button `button` in `SecondGui` GUI, the output is always `1`.
But I want that the output will be `0` or `1` based on in which GUI I select the button.

Comment: Have you tried to use a non `static` class attribute? Why doesn't it work for you if you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to create more than one object of a class that are independent
>   one from the other.

Your current code creates 2 independent objects inside this loop

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        menus.add(new SecondGui(i));
    }
```

But as you made it static, it is not bounded to any instance you creates.

What you need is an instance variable to keep the ID for the `SecondGui` instance. You can create a new constructor and pass the index of the loop.

```
public class SecondGui extends JFrame {

    private int c = 0;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;

    public SecondGui(int i) {

        this.c = i;
        initialize();
    }

    void initialize() {

        frame = new JFrame("Test");
        setSize(1024,700);
        setTitle("Menu");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        this.setLocation(50*i, 50*i);

        // Set layout manager
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        button = new JButton("B");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("C: " + c);

            }

        });

        add(button);
     }

}
```